# Extract a lambda from a Factory refactoring (with an IDE)?

Tags: java, lambda, refactoring, java-8

I have a factory which is implemented in too many places in my project, about 40. I want my code to be compatible with modern technologies and have decided to use interfaces to make sure it will be ok with Java 8 (lambdas can't implement abstract classes). Is there a safe way, i.e. a combination of refactorings to do this?

I have:

```
 class Factory{
     String name;
     protected Object globalContext;

     public abstract Session newSession();
 }
```

I need to have:

```
 interface NewSessionFunction{
     Session create(Factory enclosingFactory);
 }

 class Factory{
     protected String name;
     protected Object globalContext;

     protected final NewSessionFunction newSession;

     public Factory(NewSessionFunction newSession){
         this.newSession = newSession;
     }

     public Session newSession(){
         return newSession.create(this);
     }

     public Object getData() {return globalContext;}
 }
```

The goal is to have:

```
 new Factory((self) -> new MySession(self))
```

Instead of:

```
 new Factory(){
     public newSession(){
         return new MySession();
     }
 }
```

I haven't found a way to extract lambda yet, but curious if there is any available?

**UPDATE**

My question is how can I refactor my existing code easily as I already have 40 implementations of an abstract class. I think this refactoring feature might be introduced in IDEs if this cannot be done easily with existing tools. Many of the Java 7 codebase factories can theoretically be used with lambdas, but Java 8 does not allow instantiating them with lambdas. So a possible way out is to extract an abstract method into a lambda.

Comment: Why do you want to wrap a factory into a factory? Why don't you have just one interface Factory with one method createSession()? That should do I think.

Comment: This is a factory which creates sessions (lambdas) which do some job. I need to run this lambda in several threads, so I make copies of it.

Comment: Your current factory has additional fields and methods. Who calls this additional methods?

Comment: These fields are some global information which is used inside sessions. This information could be used to schedule or invoke other sessions. It's complicated, I've tried to simplify it as much as possible by asking for 'extract a lamda refactoring'.

Comment: What is exactly meant by `self` in the last part? The `Factory` instance that is being created in the same line?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it is the `enclosingFactory` from the declaration. It's Java's 8 syntax to instantiate a functional interface.

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATE

After a few ping-pong comments, it turns out the goal of this question to find a possibly IDE feature to help refactor abstract classes into a lambda expression in Java 8. To my knowledge, [eclipse Luna](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Java8) does not support this at this moment.

#### Answer before UPDATE

Playing with your idea:

(I already assumed) but make sure that `NewSessionFunction` is marked as a functional interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface NewSessionFunction{
  Session create(Factory f);
}
```

The following is possible

```
interface Session {
}
static class MySession implements Session {
  public MySession(Object globalContext) {
  }
}
Session s = new Factory((Factory f) -> 
  {return new MySession(f.getData());}).newSession();
```

However, the idea of `self` is not something that I've actually seen in any reference. **Do** provide a reference if you know one. In the same line, one might want to try the following which results to a compile error:

```
new Factory((Factory f) -> {
  return NewSessionFunction.this.create(f);}).newSession();
```

I am not sure how much it is feasible in your refactoring, but it might be a good idea to refactor the "shared" data into a object holder reference that can be shared among different factories of `Session` and this also makes the use of lambda expressions more straightforward and natural.

#### Answer after UPDATE

Thinking about how this can maintained with minimal change, how may the following work for you?

```
static abstract class LegacyFactory {
    private Object globalContext;
    protected Object getData() {
        return globalContext;
    }
    public abstract Session newSession();
}
@FunctionalInterface
static interface NewFactory {
    Session newSession();
}

static class FactoryWrapper {
    public static NewFactory wrap(final LegacyFactory f) {
        return () -> {
            return f.newSession();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is possible. My question is how can I refactor my existing code easily, because I already have 40 implementations of an abstract class... I think they might introduce this feature in IDEs if this cannot be done easily with existing tools. The problem of some of the existing factories is that they can be theoretically be used with lambdas, but Java 8 does not allow to instantiate them with lamdas. So a possible way out is to extract an abstract method into a lambda.

Comment: Now I see. I suggest re-titling your question to something like "Extract lambda expressions from abstract classes using an IDE?"

Comment: Interested to know what you think about the answer after update.

Comment: Well, creating a wrapper could help in some cases. I my case 40 classes is not that much to manually edit, and I didn't want to maintain two versions, so after an hour of a hard lousy job it was done: [link](https://github.com/chaschev/bear/commit/fb06e1f4d4d7d985d5fe3ece9a2243127d9e083b). I'm still interested of how this could be automatized. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Netbeans (Dev 201311200002) doesn't support this. Not sure about Eclipse. I'm not sure you'd want an IDE that can perform a bizzilion special-purpose refactorings which you'd spend more time learing than using. You just need two things:

- A compiler. It will show you all the places to fix after you've changed Factory's signature. (Yay statically typed languages!)
- copy&paste (or find&replace) to cut down on typing.

Btw, the call to your new Factory can be simplified to:

```
new Factory(Session::new);
```

Comment: I actually do use them a lot and sometimes refactorings can do wonders, especially in big projects. IDE support for me is one of the Java advantages.